# How to do browser automation in javascript natively?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, process

I am working on a javascript project where I want to perform different operations in browser like:

```
startBrowser() -> Start the browser(User Input) and opens given URL(User Input)
stopBrowser()-> Kill the specified opened browser.
getLatestURL()-> Fetched last visited URL (Doesn't matter browser is running or it's closed)
deleteAllHistory()-> Delete all the data -> Browser History, cookies, cache, saved passwords, bookmarks etc.
```

How do I do it without using any 3rd party package?

I have written some code:

```
function openBrowser(url)
{



//open chrome browser
require('child_process').exec('open ' + url); 
}
function killBrowser()
{

//close chrome browser
require('child_process').exec('killall chrome');

}

openBrowser("www.google.com")
killBrowser()
```

The above code does work like,it opens and close the browser instantly but when I call `killBrowser` method on already opened browser,it doesnt work.

Can someone help?

Comment: There is a reason why browser automation tools exist. It's because you *cannot* control a browser without them. You can open a URL but not really click around and verify expectations. Not very *well*. You need a browser driver for that and there is no native functionality for this. The browser driver is a separate piece of code that just provides an API for JS to control the browser. That's not something built into Node.

Comment: The webdriver protocol is the closest you can come, but it doesn't run in JS afaik. https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/

Comment: all the history of browsers are stored in sqlite db,is there a way I can access it using jdbc driver?